# Script answer to apt-get request "To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'" in bash

Tags: bash, debian, bash-scripting, apt, debootstrap

My script is replacing sysvinit with systemd inside a chroot while building a debian image with debootstrap.

Since this is a "dangerous" action, apt-get will ask a silly question:  "To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'"

How can I script the reply to that?

*EDIT: I tried all the -y --yes --force-yes options, but they don't work.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strangely, it seems asked even with `--force-yes`:

```
apt-get remove -y --force-yes systemd
```

However,

```
echo 'Yes, do as I say!' | apt-get remove systemd
```

worked neatly.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get has a `-y, --yes, --assume-yes` switch:

```
       Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
       run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
       changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
       package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
       abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
```

or, in alternative a `--force-yes` switch:

```
       Force yes; this is a dangerous option that will cause apt to
       continue without prompting if it is doing something potentially
       harmful. It should not be used except in very special situations.
       Using force-yes can potentially destroy your system! Configuration
       Item: APT::Get::force-yes
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/apt-get.8.html

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tested that, but it did not work. will update Q.

Comment: Ok, no problem, at the moment I'm not on a debian based system so I can't try my solution on my own and recognize it doesn't work.